# linguex refer to multiple parts of an example

Tags: cross-referencing, linguex

I frequently use linguex in my writing, and I sometimes want to reference multiple parts of an example.

```
\ex. \label{X}
  \a. This is an example \label{Xa}
  \b. This is another example \label{Xb}
  \b. yae \label{Xc}

The examples in \ref{Xa} and \ref{Xb} and more awesomer than \ref{Xc}.
```

This yields...

```
The examples in (1a) and (1b) are more awesomer than (1c).
```

However, it would be nice if I could do something like...

```
The examples in \ref{Xa,Xb} are more awesomer than \ref{Xc}.
```

...with the output...

```
The examples in (1a-b) are more awesomer than (1c).
```

I don't see anything like this in the documentation. How can I get this output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the `cleveref` package. `cleveref` allows you to define very sophisticated formats for labels, including ranges.  The `linguex` package uses two counters for examples and subexamples. In the example below I've compressed the subexample range, and left the main example range uncompressed, but this can be easily changed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{ExNo}{}{}
\crefname{SubExNo}{}{}
\renewcommand{\theExNo}{\arabic{ExNo}}
\renewcommand{\theSubExNo}{\theExNo\alph{SubExNo}}
\creflabelformat{SubExNo}{(#2#1#3)}
\creflabelformat{ExNo}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefrangelabelformat{SubExNo}{(#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6)}
\crefrangelabelformat{ExNo}{(#3#1#4)--(#5#2#6)}

\begin{document}
\ex.\label{Y}
  \ag.
    Dette er ein test paa nynorsk.\\
    This is a test in Nynorsk\\
    \trans `This is a test in Nynorsk.'
  \bg.
    Dies ist ein Test auf Deutsch.\\
    This is a test in German\\
    \trans `This is a test in German.'
  \c. An single example.
  \c. Another example.

\ex. An example.

\ex. Another example.

\ex. \label{X}
  \a. This is an example \label{Xa}
  \b. This is another example \label{Xb}
  \b. A third example \label{Xc}

The examples in \crefrange{Xa}{Xb} are more awesome than \cref{Xc}.  In examples \crefrange{Y}{X} we can see lots of things.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]